# Javascript: A function which is IIFE as well as function definition for later use

Tags: javascript, iife

I want to declare a function which is an IIFE as well as a named function so that it is invoked. I think, I can do this in the following way:

```
var callme = (function callme(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    return callme;
})('i am called');
```

The above function will output "i am called" because of IIFE. And later I can call it like this:

```
callme('i m called again');
```

Any comments on this way? Or Any other way this can be achieved? Please comment.

Comment: Just declare a function separately. Then call it. You don't need IIFE.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? It is a lot dependent on that.

Comment: Looks unnecessarily confusing to me. i would stick with a simple `function callme(msg) {} callme('i am called')`. What are you trying to achieve with the IIFE that a standard definition doesn't give you?

Comment: Not everything that is feasible is also useful.

Comment: You can't name an IIFE and call it outside the IIFE, it can only be called again within it's own scope.

Comment: @Rhumborl : In my case i am supposed to call this function initially and then do the same thing again at a later time. The only thing this avoided to me is an explicit call to this function immediately after it is declared.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why you're executing it initially - what you describe isnt an IIFE, its just a good old fashioned function

```
function callMe(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}

callme("Hello"); // logs "Hello"
```

The purpose of an IIFE could be to encapsulate part of the call and return a function pointer

```
var callMe = (function(msgPrefix){
   return function(msgSuffix){
      console.log(msgPrefix + ' ' + msgSuffix);
   }
})("Hello");

callMe("World")// logs "Hello world"
```